# How to fetch details and how to connect category and book table structure ( how to use GROUP_CONCAT)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My Problem is

I have  table named `category with  id and category-name`
and `book with id and book-name`

Please write SQL query for fetch result, result should be like

```
book1- c1,c2,c3
book2- c2,c3
book3-c4
etc.
```

Comment: Please show us what you've been trying so far..

Comment: Do you have a `book_categories` table that says which categories each book is in? If not, there's no way to link the two tables.

Comment: I Don't , but want to table structure for book_categories so that can link book and categry

Comment: did you understand @Barmar Comment `If not, there's no way to link the two tables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE book_categories (
    book_id INT,
    category_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, category_id),
    FOREIGN KEY book_id REFERENCES book (id),
    FOREIGN KEY category_id REFERENCES category (id)
)
```

Then you can use a `JOIN` to get your result:

```
SELECT book_name, GROUP_CONCAT(category_name)
FROM book AS b
JOIN book_categories AS bc ON bc.book_id = b.id
JOIN categoriy AS c ON c.id = bc.category_id
GROUP BY b.id
```